# Android : Get Phone Resolution using JAVA

Tags: java, android, padding, resolution

I'm designing an app that changes the padding of the linear layouts according to the resolution of the phone...
I've designed the XML file for a resolution of 480*800
Here is one linear layout...I have 5 in 1 page...

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="78dp"
        android:paddingLeft="120dp" >

        <Button
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/page"
        android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pages" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Now I've used this code in JAVA file::

```
l3=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
     size = new Point();
  WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
  {
       w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

       width = size.x;
       height = size.y; 
  }
  else
  {
       d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
       width = d.getWidth(); 
       height = d.getHeight(); 
  }
      height1=(height/800)*113;
width1=(width/480)*14;
l3.setPadding(width1, height1, 0, 0);
```

But the variables width and height are having fixed values 480 and 800.
So the code to get width and height pixels is not working...please help!!!!
My target API is 8,10 and 17.
Please help me with the code to find resolution(pixels) of the screen.

Comment: my main problem is that I want my application to run in all phone resolutions...
let me explain...I have 5 linear layouts...which needs to be arranged in specific positions...I am doing this using padding...but this padding dp's are different in different resolutions...my piece of code is not working for that issue...please help....

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

You can use it as follows:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics); 
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels; 
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

for density, there's

```
    int densitiy = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
```

Comment: yes but my main problem is that I want my application to run in all phone resolutions...
let me explain...I have 5 linear layouts...which needs to be arranged in specific positions...I am doing this using padding...but this padding dp's are different in different resolutions...my piece of code is not working for that issue...please help....

Comment: Why don't u make different forms for each resolution and redirect your user to the forms.... with a switch case probably

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

final int height = dm.heightPixels;
final int width = dm.widthPixels;
```